# Not able to display the json response in ajax with Spring mvc end point

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc, jsonp

Team,

I'm trying to consume a rest endpoint which returns a json response using ajax. To my luck, the rest end point is returning the response which I could track it via Network section of Google chrome.
I tried many alternatives such as,

1. Changed datatype from json to jsonp.
2. Allowed CORS on the rest point.

Still the code is not working. I have added **console.log** in **.done** function of ajax to print the response on the console and nothing is getting printed on the console.

```
function getJson(){
        var json = $.ajax({
        headers: { 
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
         },
        url: 'http://charlie-halls-91456.herokuapp.com/retrieve/date/2011-06-13/2012-06-14',

        type: "get",
            dataType: 'jsonp',
        }).done(function(response){
        alert("Response is " +response);
    });     
}
```

Comment: http://charlie-halls-91456.herokuapp.com/retrieve/date/2011-06-13/2012-06-14 link has to contain json data

Comment: I haven't shared original link. Its just a sample link i have shared. Original link does provide the json data.

Comment: check the json url using rest client in firefox..if the service returns data then we can think about cross domain issues,confirm whether service returns data properly

Comment: Yes checked with firefox and its returning data properly.